# sed command – sed 's/test/toast/' – not replacing all 'test' in file

Tags: sed

Shouldn't the second 'test' line also get replaced?
How would I have to write the command to replace all 'test'?

```
$ sed 's/test/toast/' texttest.txt 
toast file test file hahahaha 1
toast file test file hahahaha 2
```

Comment: [Using 'sed' to find and replace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159367/using-sed-to-find-and-replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already found out, `s/test/toast/` will only replace the first occurrence of "`test`" on each line with "`toast`".  To make sed replace all non-overlapping occurrences of "`test`" with "`toast`", you need to append the [global replacement flag `g`](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-6) to the replacement command, as in:

```
$ echo 'This test is a test.' | sed 's/test/toast/g'
This toast is a toast.
```

---

Note that the `g` flag only handles non-overlapping replacements, and will e.g. turn "`testest`" into "`toastest`", not into "`toastoast`":

```
$ echo 'This test is the testest test.' | sed 's/test/toast/g'
This toast is the toastest toast.
```

If you *do* want overlapping replacements, this can be [worked around using a loop](https://superuser.com/questions/1043186/overlapping-replacements-with-sed):

```
$ echo 'This test is the testest test.' | sed ':loop; s/test/toast/; t loop'
This toast is the toastoast toast.
```

---

Ps. Using `;` as a command separator, as above, is a GNU sed feature.  For BSD sed (as found e.g. on MacOS), you need to use literal newlines or multiple `-e` arguments instead:

```
$ echo 'This test is the testest test.' | sed ':loop
s/test/toast/
t loop'
This toast is the toastoast toast.

$ echo 'This test is the testest test.' | sed $':loop\n s/test/toast/\n t loop'
This toast is the toastoast toast.

$ echo 'This test is the testest test.' | sed -e ':loop' -e 's/test/toast/' -e 't loop'   
This toast is the toastoast toast.
```

(All of these will also work on GNU sed.  The second version, with `$''`, relies on [a feature of some shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371827/do-shells-other-than-bash-and-zsh-support-ansi-c-quoting-e-g-string), such as bash and zsh, and may require quoting any backslashes appearing in your sed code itself.)

Answer (score 7):

Ok, got it …

> *g Make the substitution for all non-overlapping matches of the regular
> expression, not just the first one.*

```
$ sed 's/test/toast/g' texttest.txt 
toast file toast file hahahaha 1
toast file toast file hahahaha 2
```

Comment: I believe g means global.

Comment: That's a very silly default. Now I'm wondering how many instances that I wanted to replace I've inadvertently left lying around in files when I used `sed`.